# Tumblr Integration: What is best practice for caching data from API?

Tags: api, remote-access, tumblr

I have a websites that has a blog section, which pulls the data using the Tumblr API.

My client just updates her Tumblr blog and the website would just access the Tumblr API to populate the blog page on the website. Also, any blog items tagged as news will show up on the home page.

I could be wrong, but I am sure there are limits to the rate of accessing the API, and so I am thinking I should somehow store the data in a database or even json file.

What would be a good way to "cache" the Tumblr API data so that I am not accessing the API everytime somebody views the website?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[phpTumblr](http://code.google.com/p/phptumblr/) has a caching class (class.read.tublr.cache.php)